# Getting list data from controller with AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to update my table after I delete with ajax.But I get this error `customer.js:96 Uncaught TypeError: customerViewModel.CustomersList is not iterable`.(I create the table by looping foreach inside the customerlist while the page is loading).What am I doing wrong to be able to access the customer list' via ajax?

Controller :

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Customers()
        {
           
                CustomerViewModel customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
                customerViewModel.CustomersList = customerService.GetCustomers();
                return View(customerViewModel);
        }
```

Service :

```
public List<Customers> GetCustomers()
        {
            var cstList = new List<Customers>();
            ............
            ............
            return cstList;
        }
```

I tried this :

```
function updateTable() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Customer/Customers", 
        dataType: "html", 
        success: function (customerViewModel) {
            $("#customers").empty();
            for (const item of customerViewModel.CustomersList) {
                $("#customers").append(
                    `
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">${item.musteri_id}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="me-2 text-capitalize">
                            <span class="formatted-name">${item.musteriAd}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-uppercase">${item.musteriSoyad}</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>${item.musteriTel}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-update" data-id="${item.musteri_id}" data-userName="${item.musteriAd}" data-userSurname="${item.musteriSoyad}" data-userPhone="${item.musteriTel}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-id="${item.musteri_id}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        `
                );
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: console the response and check the data received as response